# How to select row in batch edit mode using guriddo jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using latest guriddo jqgrid in batch edit mode we have textbox in row but whenever textbox got focus row selection is not happening  i have to click row border. So I want to select row on textbox got focus.
I have tried that whenever any control got selected in row beforeRowClick event is firing so in that event i have tried to setSelection method now row is selected but selectRow event is not firing why?

Answer (score 0):

There is no event called  **beforeRowClick**  in Guriddo jqGrid. Instead use **beforeSelectRow**.

It is a good idea first to [check the docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#events) and then ask.

The below code works for me

```
$(..).jqGrid({
    ...
    beforeSelectRow : function(rowid, event) {
        $(this).jqGrid('setSelection', rowid);
        return true;
    },
...
});
```

Edit: It is a good idea before to select the row with setSelction, to check if you are in edit mode for the row. This can be done if you use the editable=1 attribute of the row. Look at the docs for inline editing features.